# Using .map function for two dimensional array - React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a two dimensional array like this;

[image]

And I need to use a **map** function to display **div** elements as many as the length of the array.

I saved the state into **localStorage** to prevent the data from disappearing after refreshing the page.

```
const conditions = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("condition")).map((condition, index) => {
            return <div key={index} className="card bg-color-primary" style={{ height: "170px", width: "300px", borderColor: "#1E90FF", backgroundColor: "white", borderWidth: "2px" }}>
                    {_.isEmpty(this.state.rule.condition) ?
                        <div className="card-content" style={{ color: "black" }}>
                            <span className="card-title">New Condition</span>
                            <p>Click to edit</p>
                        </div> :
                        <div className="card-content" style={{ color: "black" }}>
                            <span className="card-title">{condition.property}</span>
                            <p>{condition.operator + " " + condition.value}</p>
                        </div>}
                    <div className="card-action">
                        <a href="javascript:;" style={{ color: "red" }}>OR</a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" style={{ color: "black" }}>AND</a>
                        <a onClick={this.handleOpen} style={{ color: "gray", cursor: "pointer" }}>EDIT</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        });
```

After this scope of code, it throws an error like;

> Uncaught TypeError: localStorage.getItem(...).map is not a function

**NOTE:** I already have JSON.parse but forgot to add it here so it is not the actual problem. My bad.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("condition")` doesn't return an array.

Comment: data is not 2D array, it's object that contains key value pair and those key is having the array so specify on which property you want to run the map.

Comment: possible cache or not compiled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data that you stored in localStorage is not a 2D array, it's an object having keys `name, operator, property, value`. To use map, data should be an array. Specify on which (field) array you want to run the map.

Also important part is, localStorage will return the stringified value, so you need to parse the it first.

Example- running map of `name` value:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("condition")).name.map(.....)
```

Or if you want to run `map` on `object` then first use **[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** (return an array of all the keys) or **[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)** (return array of all the values) to get the array first then run `map` on that.

Check this snippet:

```js
let obj = {
   a: [1,2,3],
   b: [4,5,6]
}

Object.keys(obj).map(el => {
   console.log('key', el);
   obj[el].map(sub_el => console.log(sub_el));
})
```